# connection lost while using sinatra-websocket gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, html, sinatra, websocket

I want to use websocket in sinatra in my social game and first i wanted to use em-websockets but then i found a good gem for websockets and it use em-websockets .. it's called sinatra-websocket here ..
https://github.com/simulacre/sinatra-websocket
and i have a problem that i found also in the example of the gem here 
https://github.com/simulacre/sinatra-websocket/blob/master/examples/echochat.rb

the problem is if any of the clients are idle for while (not sending or receiving) .. all the connections got an error on the browser (the connection is interrupted while loading) ..and then no client can send anything to the server by websocket !!!

anyone knows what's happening ??  thanks a lot !!